# I want to get the consutive pair of natural number all increment or decrement sequence

Tags: java, algorithm

suppose i have a array 2, 9, 0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6,12,0,3,9
so first pair should be 1,2,3 because its the fixed increment.
second pair should be 6,12
and third pair should be 0,3,9

int[] arr = {2, 9, 0, 6, 1, 2, 3, 6};

```
            System.out.println(">>>>>>>"+array(arr));

            //to get the max sequence.
            int sequenceLength = 3;
            Map<String, Integer> map = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
            int count;
            String str1, str2;
            for (int i = 0; i <= arr.length - sequenceLength; i++) {
                str1 = "";
                count = 0;
                for (int a = i; a < i + sequenceLength; a++) {
                        str1 += "" + arr[a];
                    }
                if (map.get(str1) != null) {
                    continue;
                } else {
                    map.put(str1, count);
                }

                for (int ii = i; ii <= arr.length - sequenceLength; ii++) {
                    str2 = "";
                    for (int a = ii; a < ii + sequenceLength; a++) {
                        str2 += "" + arr[a];
                    }
                    if (str1.equals(str2)) {
                        count++;
                        map.put(str1, count);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Why isn't 0,6 a pair?

Comment: yes it can sorry i didn't mention it

Comment: but what is the issue?

Comment: A "pair" means exactly two things, so `1, 2, 3` isn't a pair. Also, what criteria are you using that can include `6, 12` but excludes `2, 9`?

Comment: i want the pair. not able to solve...

Comment: its not about the pair . getting consutive sequece of pair

Comment: Do you mean you want runs of increasing numbers? But then why not `1, 2, 3, 6, 12`?

Comment: @Boann need is exact next increment like 1,2,3

Comment: and 3,6 and 6,12 but not 3,6,12

Comment: But you said you wanted `0, 3, 9` and that isn't an "exact next increment".

Comment: Now you say you want decrementing sequences as well, so why not `9, 0` and `6, 1` and `12, 0`?

Comment: but at this moment only increment not decrement

Answer (score 0):

PSEUDO CODE:

```
incrementArray = new Array<pair>
increasingSequences = new Array<pair> //size of N
increasingSequenceCount = 0    //You start with 0 incrementing arrays
for i -> N
    value = array[i];
    for j -> incrementArray.length
        if (incremtentArray[j] == value + incrementArray[j])
            addValueToIS(value, j) //adds to array j of increasingSequences
        else
           incrementArray.close(j) //closes increasingSequence array
    incrementArray.push(array[i], increasingSequenceCount++);
```

At the end increasingSequences will contain X number of arrays of size > 1. These are your sequences